# Is it possible for a WCF service to restart itself?

Tags: c#, vb.net, wcf

I'm currently working on a WCF service which holds and processes all the data for an application, while a MySql database is used for persistence. The service currently works as a singleton (`InstanceContextMode.Single`) and supports multiple concurrent calls (`ConcurrencyMode.Multiple`). I'm not really sure what version of IIS the service is hosted in, but I believe it is IIS 7.5.

The problem is that there are some situations where if an exception occurs (eg.: while releasing `ReaderWriterLockSlim` locks), the service will be in a unreliable state and data may get corrupted (and written into the database) if users keep calling the service.

Currently I know of two ways of preventing users from calling the service: either closing the `InstanceContext` object (through `OperationContext.Current`) or raising an exception in `IDispatchMessageInspector.AfterReceiveRequest` if the service is in a faulted state. The problem with both of these two ways is that they make the service unavailable until I restart the server/application pool (which I can't, see note below) or re-deploy the service.

Important note: Although I have Full-Trust, the service is currently hosted on a shared server, so I can't restart the server or the entire application pool (if that is possible) because that would restart other people's services as well.

## Update:

I tried unloading the AppDomain as @usr suggested, but that doesn't work as well: after unloading it, an exception is raised for every call to the service.

Currently I'm trying to find out what WCF/IIS uses as a condition to decide if the service should be created again. I noticed that in the code generated for the client checks if there is any channel available to communicate with the service; if there isn't, a new one is created. Thus, I tried to close all channels in the service: I tried closing `OperationContext.Current.InstanceContext.OutgoingChannels`, `OperationContext.Current.InstanceContext.IncomingChannels`, `OperationContext.Current.Channel`, and many other properties with "Channel" in their name, all of them with no success.

Comment: Is it hosted in IIS? Because this kind of management is not a task for the Service itself but for the Hosting process.

Comment: And why do you use Single Instance mode?

Comment: @Henk Yes, it is hosted on IIS. And the choice to use single instance mode is by design: the application is a little game,  and the service is responsible for holding the world state and processing every operation on it.

Comment: You can unload the appdomain. Not sure how clean this is.

Comment: @usr Unloading the AppDomain does not work: the service remains inaccessible after doing so until the server is restarted or the service is re-uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

The way to warm-up anything in IIS prior to version 7.5 is using scheduled console application to ping your web site / services and warm them up. It's not a good fix but it works, it is easy and I saw it on every project which had to deal with this requirement.

Or If you are using IIS 7.5 then 
You can use `Windows Server AppFabric`, it has Auto Stat feature to keep the service always on. But you need to be on `IIS 7.5` to install `App Fabric`.

Comment: The problem isn't exactly how to warm the service up. Consider this: the service is already running, then an exception is unhandled in a critical point. From this point on, I can't let the users perform any other operation in the service, as data may get corrupted and written to the database; I need to restart the service, so that the next call to it creates a new instance (just like the first call to the service after it is uploaded).